# Call function from function

Tags: jquery

I can't really get my jQuery functions to colabirate as intended, the only console.log I get is this

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: quiz is not defined*

I have looked around on how to properly call a function from a function and I would say I did as the results I got from it.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Quizinator!</title>
      <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/quiz.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<section id="Coding">
<h1><span>[Quiz]</span> Coding<span>[Hard]</span></h1>

<content id="Coding" class="0">
<h2>Is this working?</h2>
<button type="submit" class="correct">Yes</button>
<button type="submit">No</button>
</content>

</section>



<section id="Facebook">
<h1><span>[Quiz]</span> Facebook<span>[Normal]</span></h1>

<content id="Facebook" class="0">
<h2>Is this working?</h2>
<button type="submit" class="correct">Yes</button>
<button type="submit">No</button>
</content>

</section>


<section id="Games">
<h1><span>[Quiz]</span> Games<span>[Easy]</span></h1>

<content id="Games" class="0">
<h2>Is this working?</h2>
<button type="submit" class="correct">Yes</button>
<button type="submit">No</button>
</content>

</section>

<section id="Child">
<h1><span>[Quiz]</span>Common sense<span>[Dumb Easy]</span></h1>

<content id="Child" class="0">
<h2>Is this working?</h2>
<button type="submit" class="correct">Yes</button>
<button type="submit">No</button>
</content>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#333;
}
content {
    position:fixed;
    left:25%;top:20%;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50%;
}

content h2 {
    margin:0%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    padding:1%;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}

content button {
    text-align:center;
    padding:1%;
    width:200px;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    margin-left:20%;
    font-size:18px;
}

content button:nth-child(6), content button:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left:5%;
}

content p {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    font-size:20px;
    color:red;
    background-color:black;
    padding:1%;
}

content .score {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
}

content:last-of-type h2 {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
}

section {
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

section h1 {
    padding:3%;
    color:white;
    margin:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

section:nth-child(1) h1 {
    background-color:#FF4136;
}

section:nth-child(2) h1 {
    background-color:#FF851B;
}

section:nth-child(3) h1 {
    background-color:#2ECC40;
}

section:nth-child(4) h1 {
    background-color:#39CCCC;
}

section h1 {
    text-align:center;
}

section h1 span:nth-child(1) {
    float:left;
}

section h1 span:nth-child(2) {
    float:right;
}
```

jQuery

```
var score = [0, 10];
var life = 3;
var delay = 500;
var game;

$(function quiz() {
    console.log(game) /* Problem Maker */
});

$(function() {
    $('section').on('click', function() {
        game = $(this).attr('id');

            /* CHECK ACTIVE GAME */
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {

         if(confirm('Exit game')) {
            /* EXIT GAME */
            $(this).removeClass('active')
            $('section').slideDown(delay);
         }

        } else {
        if(confirm('Do you want to start the ' + game + ' quiz?')) {
            /* START GAME */
        $(this).siblings().slideUp(delay);
        $(this).addClass('active');
            quiz();
        } else {

            /* CANCEL GAME */ 
            console.log('false')
        }
        return;
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667955/how-can-i-access-the-functions-wrapped-in-the-document-readyfunction-of

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing the boundary between jQuery and JavaScript.

The `quiz` function seems to be simply reporting game values to the console and doesn't need to be defined via jQuery.

Just define `quiz` on it's own:

```
function quiz() {
    console.log(game)
}
```

When you wrap it in that jQuery block it's scope is no longer global which is why you are getting the reference error.

Here is a good article to read to getting started with JavaScript and scoping: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Thanks, that indeed did the trick!